# Finding the time between two dates in Perl

Tags: perl, datetime

I am trying to calculate and display, in minutes, the difference between the entered date and the present time. I have:

```
print "Enter a date YYYY MM DD. Remember perl's months go from 0-11.\n";
while ( @dateEnt < 1 ) {
    my $dateEntered = <STDIN>;
    chomp $dateEntered;
    push @dateEnt, $dateEntered;

    (@datedata) = split( /\s+/, $dateEntered );
    $year  = $datedata[0];
    $month = $datedata[1];
    $day   = $datedata[2];
}

$time         = time;
$readabletime = localtime($time);

use Time::Local;
$timeB = localtime [1];
$timeBetween = $readabletime[1] - $timeB;
print "The time between the dates is $timeBetween\n";
```

When I execute this, I get nothing for an answer. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and to the _perl_ tag. Please make sure you always add `use strict;` and `use warnings` to your programs. They help you spot mistakes early. If you are learning Perl from a source that shows neither, it is outdated. You are better off using one from the Perl tag wiki here on SO. Now, you are never using the date that your user enters. And there are some syntax errors. Please start with `use strict` and `use warnings`.

Comment: ... and by "outdated" we mean literally decades old. `use warnings` was introduced in 2000; `use strict` was introduced in 1994.

Answer (score 3):

Lets take a look at this last chunk

```
use Time::Local; 
$timeB = localtime[1]; 
$timeBetween = $readabletime[1] - $timeB; 
print "The time between the dates is $timeBetween\n";
```

The `use` statement is normally put at the top of the program because it's actually executed at compile time, but it's fine anywhere really

`localtime[1]` looks like you're trying to access the second element (Perl arrays start at index zero) of an array called `localtime`. But what you're actually doing is creating an anonymous array that contains the single value 1 and passing a reference to it to `localtime`. If you try `print[1]` instead, you'll see that you get something like `ARRAY(0x22c4000)`. So `localtime` is trying to convert a memory address into a date and time

`$readabletime[1]` is attempting to access the second element of array `@readabletime`, which doesn't exists so it will evaluate to `undef`

You end up trying to subtract something like the *string* `"Thu Mar  4 18:50:24 1971"` from `undef` which is meaningless. I think you should get a fatal error something like

```
Argument "Thu Mar  4 18:50:24 1971" isn't numeric in subtraction
```

Answer (score 3):

`use strict;` and `use warnings;` would have told you about a lot of the problems.

- that `while` loop is redundant, because you `push` without any validation. So it'll *always* be true on the second iteration.
- which makes `@dateEnt` redundant.
- `localtime` in a scalar context gives a string. You cannot do maths with a string. (Occasionally you can cheat, because `perl` can convert it to a number, but that doesn't work with a date string).
- `use` is usually at the top of a program, because it's the first thing 'done' regardless
- `localtime` in an array context returns an array of values.  `($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime(time);` you *can* do `(localtime)[1]` which gives you `$min`. But that's not too meaningful for comparing anyway.
- `$readabletime[1]` refers to the second element of an array called `@readabletime`. This doesn't exist.

So to accomplish what you're after - I would suggest using `Time::Piece` (core perl module) like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece

my $date;
while ( not $date ) {
    print "Enter a date YYYY MM DD\n";
    my $dateEntered = <STDIN>;
    chomp $dateEntered;
    $date = Time::Piece->strptime( $dateEntered, "%Y %m %d" );
}
print "Understood: $date\n";
my $timebetween_s = ( time() - $date->epoch );
print $timebetween_s, "s between then and now\n";
```

Note - it uses `strptime` to convert the entered date to a `Time::Piece` object (which you can just `print` if you want and get a stringified date, but you can also do other transformations). `strptime` supports lots of different formats.

But you just subtract `$date->epoch` - which gets the time in seconds since 1st Jan 1970, from `time()` which is also the time in seconds since 1st Jan 1970. This gives you a time delta like you want - in seconds. You'll need to divide it if you want different units.

Comment: If you use `Time::Seconds` as well, you can write `my $time_between = (localtime - $date)->pretty` and get it nicely formatted

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime;

my $from_date = DateTime->new(
                       year   => 2014,
                       month  => 9,
                       day    => 24,
                       hour   => 9,
                       minute => 13,
                       second => 8,
                       time_zone => 'local',
                     );
print "$from_date\n";
my $current_date = DateTime->now( time_zone => 'local' )->set_time_zone('floating');
print "$current_date\n";
my $time_diff = $current_date - $from_date;
print 'year = ', $time_diff->years, "\n";
print 'month = ', $time_diff->months, "\n";
print 'days = ', $time_diff->days, "\n";
print 'hours = ', $time_diff->hours, "\n";
print 'minutes = ', $time_diff->minutes, "\n";
print 'secondss = ', $time_diff->seconds, "\n";
```

Result:

```
2014-09-24T09:13:08
2015-09-25T21:31:37
year = 1
month = 0
days = 1
hours = 12
minutes = 18
secondss = 29
```